# How to obtain the residuals of mosaic and mosaicplots

Tags: r, plot, categorical-data

I have the following mosaic plots.

```
library(vcd)
data("HairEyeColor")
mosaic(HairEyeColor, shade = TRUE)
mosaicplot(HairEyeColor, shade = TRUE)
```

The shading shows the st.residuals. How can I extract these values? What kind of residuals are they? What kind of model is being fitted?

Many thanks

Comment: You can have some information reading `?strucplot`

Comment: Doesn't help much I'm afraid.

Comment: "If residuals is NULL, residuals_type must be one of "pearson"
(default; giving components of Pearson’s chi-squared)"